# Using Git to sync Mac and Android

Tags: mac, git, android, sync

I have a folder on my **Mac** and corresponding folder on my **Android** phone, which I would like to keep in sync both ways. ie. sometimes work is done on my phone, sometimes work is done on my Mac.

I technically don't require versioning history, but nevertheless it's a nice to have.

I have tried `Google Drive - Backup & Sync` for this purpose, but I didn't like the fact that I require a special file explorer on my phone and it "streams" the files so the access is always laggy.

I also don't want to use `DropBox` for similar reasons.

I have `termux` running on my phone and have been able to sync via a remote origin on **Atlassian BitBucket**, however the problem I'm foreseeing is that BitBucket have set a limit ([1GB soft/2GB hard](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/what-kind-of-limits-do-you-have-on-repositoryfile-size/)) on the size of the repository specifically to curb being used as a file-sharing service.

Is there a better way to do this than `Git`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is not a backup or syncing tool.  Git can sync data that's versioned, sure, but its goal is to be a version control system, and as you've found, it doesn't work very well as a syncing tool.  For example, Git doesn't sync most permissions across machines.

If you don't want to sync the two with a cloud syncing service, you can do so with a tool like `rsync`, which is usually used in conjunction with SSH.  There are a variety of other tools out there as well.

If you want to use `rsync`, you can do `rsync -a --delete-after SOURCE DEST`.  Generally, one of those paths will be a remote rsync location and one will be a local path.

Comment: I like the `rsync` proposal, but can you please expand on how it could be used? my dilemma is that files will be added and removed on both the `remote` and `local` sides, i need changes to either side to be reflected - git is very good at doing this because there is a `commit` stage to the process

Comment: that is i want: *removed* on `local` -> *removed* on `remote`; *added* on `local` -> *added* on `remote`; *removed* on `remote` -> *removed* on `local`; *added* on `remote` -> *added* on `local`

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain some command line options to use.

Comment: i've accepted this answer because it pointed me in the right direction and Mecki's solution on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120408) got me very close to where i wanted to get

Answer (score -1):

you can try using syncthing or folder sync app.

Comment: Explaining HOW to use these tools to solve the problem presented may make it an answer. Right now it is just a comment, and as such, does not belong here. If you wish to improve this please use the EDIT button to do so.